# how to get value of an XCUIElement?

Tags: xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

How to get the value of `textfield` in XCODE7 UITesting?

```
var b = XCUIApplication().childrenMatchingType(.textField).elementBoundByIndex(0).stringValue
```

Answer (score 16):

Let's suppose you have a Text Field like so:

[image: textField]

(I'm hardcoding it's value there ("My Text") for the sake of the example.)

**Give it an `Accessibility Label`. In this case, I'm giving it the "Text Field" label.**

Now to access its value, you could do something like:

```
func testExample() {

    let app = XCUIApplication()        
    let textField = app.textFields["Text Field"]
    XCTAssertTrue(textField.value as! String == "My Text")

    // So basically "textField.value"
}
```

On a side note: when in doubt on how to access certain properties of a given `XCUIElement`, I found that its [debugDescription](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/1500909-debugdescription) helps a lot.

For example, set a breakpoint after the property declaration, execute the test, wait for the app to stop at the breakpoint, go to `lldb console`, type `po propertyName.debugDescription`, and check the output:

[image: output]

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Lets assume I want to get the string that gets printed for the nav bar of my app

[image]

What I did was I created a XCUIElement for my nav bar:

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
XCUIElement *navBarTitle = [app.navigationBars elementBoundByIndex:0];
```

I then put a breakpoint after the creation of the navBarTitle object and used the debug console to print out the details of the navBarTitle object:

[image: print out]

You see in the print out of the debug console that there is a **key** called ***identifier***.

To extract that string from that object, I created an NSString object using the following method:

```
NSString *nameofuser = [navBarTitle valueForKey:@"identifier"];
```

I used the XCUIElement navBarTitle and then used the method **valueForKey**. valueForKey extracts the string value for the key identifier.

You can read up about this method here:
[NSKeyValueCoding](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/1657268-nskeyvaluecoding?language=objc)

valueForKey is the KEY to unlocking the answer to this question....pun intended :)

Comment: I cannot upvote this enough! The "po..." in lldb is a life saver!

Comment: Thanks so much! On swift, it was - myElement.value(forKey: "identifier")

Answer (score 0):

app.staticTexts.element(boundBy: 1).label

Comment: Welcome to SO, please refer to this for better presenting your answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/3519504